# Del part of list in python by for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to remove some words from string list of words.

`list1= "abc dfc kmc jhh jkl"`.

My goal is to remove the words from `'dfc'` to `'jhh'`. I am new in Python, so I am trying some things with the index from c#, but they don't work here.

I am trying this:

```
index=0
for x in list1:
  if x=='dfc'
    currentindex=index
    for y in list1[currentindex:]
        if y!='jhh'
           break;
        del list1[currentindex]
        currentindex=index
  elif x=='jhh'
       break;
```

Comment: if list1 is a string, as your post indicates, your outer loop will go through list1 character by character (x is a character, so will never match a 3-character string).

Comment: You seem to have provided a string for list1. If it's a string, use the re package. re.sub() with do the job .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, split the string into words:

```
list1 = "abc dfc kmc jhh jkl"
words = list1.split(" ")
```

Next, iterate through the words until you find a match:

```
start_match = "dfc"
start_index = 0
end_match = "jhh"
end_index = 0
for i in range(len(words)):
    if words[i] == start_match:
        start_index = i
    if words[i] == end_match:
        end_index = j
        break
print ' '.join(words[:start_index]+words[end_index+1:])
```

Note: In the case of multiple matches, this will delete the least amount of words (choose the last start_match and first end_match).

Comment: Thank you, this works fine.I just need to make it in a new list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a long for loop, a simple slice in Python does the trick:

```
words = ['abc', 'dfc', 'kmc', 'jhh', 'jkl']

del words[1:4]
print(words)
```

indexes start at 0. So you want to delete index 1-3. We enter 4 in the slice because Python stops -1 before the last index argument (so at index 3). Much easier than a loop.

Here is your output:

```
['abc', 'jkl']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = "abc dfc kmc jhh jkl"
>>> print(a.split("dfc")[0] + a.split("jhh")[1])
abc  jkl
```

You can do this sample treatment with lambda:

```
b = lambda a,b,c : a.split(b)[0] + a.split(c)[1]
print(b(a, "dfc", "jhh"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`list1= "abc dfc kmc jhh jkl".split()` makes list1 as follows:

`['abc', 'dfc', 'kmc', 'jhh', 'jkl']`

Now if you want to remove a list element you can try either

`list1.remove(item) #removes first occurrence of 'item' in list1`

Or

`list1.pop(index) #removes item at 'index' in list1`

Comment: Don't think this is what the question is asking. OP wants to replace all words between two words, not replace instances of a word.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of words by splitting the string

```
list1= "abc dfc kmc jhh jkl".split()
```

Then iterate over the list, using a flag variable to indicate whether an element should be deleted from the list

```
flag = False   
for x in list1:
    if x=='dfc':
        flag = True
    if x == 'jhh':
        list1.remove(x)
        flag = False
    if flag == True:
        list1.remove(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with what you have tried, especially:

1. `list1` is a string, not a list
2. when you write `list1[i]`, you get the character at index `i` (not a word)
3. in your for loop, you try to modify the string you iterate on: it is a very bad idea.

Here is my one-line style suggestion using `re.sub()`, which simply substitute a part of the string matching with the given regex pattern. It may be sufficient for your purpose:

```
import re

list1= "abc dfc kmc jhh jkl"
list1 = re.sub(r'dfc .* jhh ', "", list1)

print(list1)
```

Note: I kept the identifier `list1` even if it is a string.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```
  test = list1.replace("dfc", "")
```

Comment: Don't think this is what the question is asking. OP wants to replace all words between two words, not replace instances of a word.